# How to change wpf richTextBox background color in the designer and not in code?

Tags: c#, wpf

This is by code :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            RichTextBoxLogger.Background = Brushes.Black;
            CenterWindowOnScreen();
        }
```

but what if i want to set the background color of the richTextBox control in the designer and not in the code ? because in the designer the richTextBox background color is still white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually a RichTextBlox contains a [FlowDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.flowdocument?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), try by setting the background of the document instead.